# Apache Symfony Vitrual Host

Tags: apache, symfony

I clone project in /home/ivan/host/name/web and create virtual host. a2ensite and reload and restart server.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName name.local
DocumentRoot /home/ivan/host/name/web
DirectoryIndex app.php
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/name-error.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/name-access.log combined
<Directory "/home/ivan/host/name/web">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
</Directory>
```

and hosts

```
127.0.0.1       name.local
```

but have

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

I doing chmod 777 -R host/ but still have error 
what I'am doing wrong ?

**SOLVED**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName aog.local
DocumentRoot /home/ivan/host/name/web
DirectoryIndex app.php
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/name-error.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/name-access.log combined
<Directory "/home/ivan/host/name/web">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Allow from All
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like you are using apache 2.4,
add directive Require all granted as shown below:

```
<Directory /home/ivan/host/name/web>
    AllowOverride All
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: I not understand this is because another permission for this directory host? for all permission Require all granted?

Comment: It was replacement for allow from all, according to upgrade docs, http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/upgrading.html